# Defining various DB & Salesforce access information in Mule Anypoint Studio

Tags: configuration-files, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am running Mule Anypoint studio v6.2.4 under Windows. I have an application which gets data records from a SQL Server DB and populates them into Salesforce Org. The application was developed using examples and works fine in the current scenario of one DB and one SF parameters defined in `mule.{mule.env}.properties` file.

Now I need to access a different DB for input records and populate them to a different Salesforce org. Changing the access parameters in properties file every time is tedious and error prone. (e.g. 4 DB's & 4 SF Orgs}

What I would like to do is define access parameters (for various SQL Server DB and Salesforce Orgs), specify DbName and SFName as http query parameters, and let mule application pick the correct parameters for connection.

How would I accomplish it? Details will help me as I am not that proficient in Mule yet.

Thanks

Kishore

Comment: is this what you want? A property file with a list of DBs, then being able through QUERY PARAMETERS to specify the DBName that will be used by DBConnector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create one property file with a full list of the database connections:

```
#DB of puppies
postgres.puppies.user=mule
postgres.puppies.password=password
postgres.puppies.host=db-1
postgres.puppies.db=mule-puppies

#DB of cars
postgres.cars.user=mule
postgres.cars.password=password
postgres.cars.host=db-2
postgres.cars.db=mule-cars
```

## UPDATED

Then, if yout want to read a query parameter from the dataweave component loading one of your Properties:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
p("postgres." ++ inboundProperties."http.query.params"['db-name'] ++ ".user")
```

*Note*: Consider when `QueryParameter.db-name` is null you will get an exception (you should handle this exception), or, another way to do it, is by handling nulls from your own data-weave (https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/28105/how-do-i-do-a-null-check-in-dataweave.html), e.g. when null you could define a default database

Hope this helps clarifying

Comment: Wouldn't this require adding new dataweave component whenever a new db or salesforce org is added.  What I would like is specify db-name query parameter with "puppies" as value and  use the dataweave as 
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
   user : p("postgres." + #[db-name] + ".user"),
   ...
}

This will eliminate separate choice/dataweave blocks and one block may be good enough. Just not sure how to put it and need help

Comment: Understood kishore, can you check the UPDATE subheader in my asnwer?

Comment: thanks. I need to see how to fit the solution in my mule application as it uses batch flow. Will post accordingly.

Comment: Alberici, I have been drawn into another project hence couldn't try out your solution. Soon I will be putting the solution in a batch oriented mule script to see how it behaves. Will let you know for sure.

Comment: did a quick check. It works OK, but ran into a related problem. I would like to keep the "property file" as an external file so that every mule script can use it and I don't have to maintain it as property file in every mule script. Any idea how to get it done. Or should I ask a new question.

Comment: nice! glad to help kishore, sure, I suggest you create a new question that way is easy for future people to find it out, I have ideas on how to achieve what you are saying but have to try

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. That is the correct approach. Posted the question and hope to get the solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: all properties defined in which file