# Defining various DB & Salesforce access information in an external file and using them in Mule Anypoint Studio

Tags: configuration-files, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I am running Mule Anypoint studio v6.2.4 under Windows. I have an application which gets data records from a SQL Server DB and populates them into Salesforce Org. The application was developed using examples and works fine in the current scenario of one DB and one SF parameters defined in a mule.properties file. This structure works but with serious limitations. Whenever a new DB instance is provided (DEV/QA/SAT/UAT...) and a different destination SF Org is chosen, all the mule applications need to be modified as the access parameters are defined in the property file.

I asked for help about how to dynamically define and use the access parameters in this question. ([Defining various DB & Salesforce access information in Mule Anypoint Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885045/defining-various-db-salesforce-access-information-in-mule-anypoint-studio)). While the proposed solution worked, it was still based on property file approach. Hence whenever a new DB or SF Org is to be worked on, all the mule applications will still need to be changed because of the property file approach.

A correct approach will be define all the access parameters in an external file. In the mule app, retrieve the appropriate access parameters based on DB name or Org name (provided as http query parameters). Use their values to initialise appropriate mule script variables. This way new DBs or Orgs can be added at will and mule app should work without any re-compilation or changes.

My mule app is batch based and config code fragment to access SQL DB is as follows::

```
<db:generic-config name="legacyDB" url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:${dbHost}:${dbPort};databaseName=${dbName};user=${dbUser};password=${dbPassword}" doc:name="Generic DB Config"/>
```

How would I accomplish it so that DB or SF access works as defined? Details will help me as I am not that proficient in Mule yet.

Thanks

Kishore

Answer (score 0):

What about reading an external file using a JavaClass and returning a JavaObject to Mule, then you can easily manage those values.

Check this project and change the path in the *LoadExternalFile.java* to load your own json file. There is an example in the src/main/resources

https://github.com/angelalberici/external-property